# How to make div expand when its content?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

i am using Bootstrap 4, and making a note app with Python3 and flask, i need to set default height to the page, and when content of note is more than the height it will expand .

but the problem, its not expanding, its just taking the content to outside the div ?

```
<div class="container">
   <div style="width: 100%; height:550px;" class="jumbotron">
         {{ mark | safe }}
</div>
</div>
```

example:

i need to set the height to 550px;, and when user write a content more than to my page, so expand the jumbotron height ...

i have searched a lot before asking here, i didn't get a clear answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `min-height` instead of `height`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height` so the container grows with the content, but keeps its minimum height.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height